# Pass variable from controller to model

Tags: ee-1.12, mvc

I have spent the last couple of days trying to figure out how to pass variables from my controller to my model. I am trying to build a very simple product filter that takes some form inputs and builds a product collection based on them. I have the form built and I am using AJAX:

```
jQuery.ajax(
    {
        url: formURL,
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            location : location,
            width : width
        },
        success: function() {
            alert('form good');
        },
        error: function() {
            alert('form issue');
        } 
    });
```

to post to my controller:

```
    class Custom_GateSelector_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    public function indexAction() 
    {
        $gate_location = $this->getRequest()->getPost('location');
        $gate_width    = $this->getRequest()->getPost('width');
    }
}
```

Then I need the two variables there to be available in my model:

```
    class Custom_GateSelector_Model_Products extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Product
{
  public function getItemsCollection()
  {
      $topStairs = 'yes';
      $gateWidth = 29.00;
      $rootcatID = Mage::app()->getStore()->getRootCategoryId();

      $collection = $this->getCollection()
          ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
          ->addAttributeToFilter('gate_max_width', array('gt' => $gateWidth))
          ->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array('in' => $rootcatID))
          ->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', array('eq' => 'simple'))                                         
          ->addAttributeToSort('price', 'DESC')                                                               
          ->addAttributeToFilter('status', array('eq' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED)); 

      return $collection;
  }
}
```

I've tried the `Mage::register('gate-location', $gate_location);` method but I can't access them in the Model class from some reason.

Comment: I tried to solve the same issue. To find a solution, this post was really helpfull: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4006183/magento-passing-data-between-a-controller-and-a-block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after a long week of pulling out my hair I came to realize that the best way to pass info from a controller to a model is don't. Thanks to Ben @ Sonassi for answering an unrelated question which made me realize I can use

```
Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('location');
```

to get the post variable inside the model's action to access what I needed.

Answer (score 3):

So you basically want to pass a variable from one class to another?

If that is what you want to achieve, why not pass them in as method parameters? `getItemsCollection` is iirc not defined in any parent class – so you are free to change its signature:

```
public function getItemsCollection($gateLocation, $gateWidth)
{
    // …
}
```

If you want to avoid that for whatever reason, you can still modify the collection afterwards:

```
$collection = $gsProduct->getItemsCollection();
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('gate_max_width', array('gt' => $gateWidth))
```

Comment: I think this is the proper solution for this problem, since it does not couple the model to a post request. That's why I vote this up.

Answer (score 1):

If you will the model

`Custom_GateSelector_Model_Products` on  this `indexAction()` then it would get  those parameters on model.

**So,call  below functions on getItemsCollection**

```
$gate_location = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost('location');
$gate_width    = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost('width');
```

As per as magento system ,you cannot get current controller cannot get to another page

Comment: I'm not sure I understand